# Query table which whose name changes everyday - Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which is like - `'numberedlanding_20210606_storefront'`

this table is generated every day and changes in the time stamp. For example, nextday table name would be  `'numberedlanding_20210607_storefront'`

I am writing a query that uses this table as a base table and does further does aggregations such as -

For example -

```
with df1 as (select * from 'numberedlanding_20210606_storefront' where col1>0),

df2 as (select *,col1/col2 as test from df1),

select * from df1 a join df2 b on a.name=b.name
```

Now since this table name changes everyday how do I make it dynamic in this query?

I tried looking into Bigquery's wildcard but I think it applies on to variable at the end of the name, I want to change the name which is in the middle.

Also, here is something which I tried but was not successful -

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  getTableName() AS ((CONCAT("numberedlanding_",FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)),"_storefront")));

SELECT
  getTableName()
```

This just gives me the table name I want to use. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Just curious why this design creates all these tables instead of just one table and storing the date in it?  How many rows are in the table?

Comment: check out [Wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference)

Comment: Hey, this is just an example, I am actually using analysis in these multiple tables, and for all those analyses, the base table is the table I have mentioned above. Essentially I wanted to point out that I have to use With statement for my job and how can I basically use a dynamic name in that with statement. 
The table has about 50 million rows

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant can I use wildcards to change the name in the middle of the text like in this case?

Comment: no, only suffix. but it still should work in your case

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Could you please help me with an example? I am really confused and having brain fog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM numberedlanding_* WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = CURRENT_DATE() || '_storefront'
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense now. 
Although I am getting an error while doing this - 

Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "*"

Comment: you might need to wrap-up table reference with backticks. anyway  - check documentation. link is available in my comments above